# How to prevent bash from transforming arguments?

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line, wildcards, arguments

I am trying to use an argument of the script to find other files. The problem is that when i give the script the argument `x.*` in the command line, it is transformed into `x.sh`. Any ideas how i can get the `x.*` inside my script?

The script in comand line : `./script.sh x.*`.
If i try to print `$1` it outputs `x.sh`.

Comment: Is there, by chance, a file named x.sh there? Your * is not quoted...

Comment: Thank you, that really helped, i had a script named "x.sh"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it from the inside of your script. `*` has to be *escaped*, otherwise it will try to fit filenames (in your case `x.`, then anything, as `*` is a glob operator that matches any string in filename). You can do it in, basically, three ways - enclose your string with single or double quotes:

```
./script.sh "x.*"
./script.sh 'x.*'
```

Or prefix problematic character with backslash:

```
./script.sh x.\*
```

As Jeff mentioned in the comments (thanks), you can also disable glob expansion with:

```
set -o noglob
```

You can turn it back on with `set +o noglob` if you want to.

Comment: Set -o noglob would do it

Comment: @JeffSchaller Ah, I looked just in `shopt`. Will edit the answer accordingly, thanks.

Comment: **Any** quoting will prevent the expansion of `*`. So, you show `'x.*'` and `x.\*` but you are missing `"x.*"`. That's three ways.

Comment: @BinaryZebra That's right, included that too. Thanks.